# Can I publish a technical paper on more than one publishing sites?

Tags: publications, journals

Can I publish my technical paper on more than one publishing sites? The paper content is the same while only the formats differ. I am the author of the paper.

Comment: Sounds like self-plagiarism to me, so no.

Comment: You can, but you should not. Unless your paper is an open access paper under certain licenses like the Creative Commons and you want to post it on different **websites** or **repositories** (not academic journals).

Comment: @dgraziotin good point, but since the OP talks about changing formats I'm guessing academic journals are implied.

Comment: To expand on @dgraziotin's comment, sites like the arXiv would be considered repositories in this sense.  It's completely fine to post to several of them (if you're in a field like math/physics/CS in which posting to repositories is generally allowed by publishers).  As for academic journals, there are rare occasions in which a journal paper may be reprinted by another journal, but only with the knowledge and permission of everyone involved, and it's pretty rare.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Short answer : No.

Long answer: Only under certain circumstances where you have explicit permission to do so. Be aware that even if you have permission to do so, there are many folks who take an extremely dim view of multiple publishing.

Comment: ok. Thanks @JohnPercivalHackworth for your comments.

Answer (score 1):

The only formal process that I'm aware of is the reprint mechanism. You publish a piece of work. Sometime later, editors of a compendium or collection wish to take your article and reprint it. In that case, the original publishers have to approve this (as well as you of course).

More commonly, papers published in a peer-reviewed venue might also appear in a Ph.D dissertation in some form. Here again, there's some form of copyright approval needed for it to happen.